# Friendly links not working with get array

Tags: .htaccess, friendly-url

I got htaccess but It is not working and $_GET is empty.
I got link http://localhost:3000/?noCalc=14b4daaf66cd5e99403985bd85a4bf62
and I need http://localhost:3000/noCalc/14b4daaf66cd5e99403985bd85a4bf62
Anyone got any idea?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -MultiViews
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /kalkulator/services/calculate.php
RewriteRule ^noCalc/([^/]*)$ /?noCalc=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

$_GET noCalc is in index.php (/?noCalc) or in /kalkulator/services/calculate.php? I changed order of rules, please check:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    Options -MultiViews
    Options -Indexes
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^noCalc/(.*)$ /?noCalc=$1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /kalkulator/services/calculate.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: $_GET with variable noCalc is in index.php.
Still nothing... I mean when Im going to http://localhost:3000/noCalc/14b4daaf66cd5e99403985bd85a4bf62, $_GET still empty.

Comment: Hmm, request http://localhost:3000/?noCalc=14b4daaf66cd5e99403985bd85a4bf62 working fine?